# HTML-CSS - custom div popup on hover not appearing once the code is put inside of a div

Tags: css, html, web, popup

I have some code that spawns a popup (created in a div) when the user hovers over an image.
But once i put this code into a div, the pop up no longer appears.

HTML:

```
    <div id="tabs" style="width:100%">  
    <div id="wellsTab" style="position:relative; left: background-image:url(buttons/wells_background_off.png); 
            background-repeat:no-repeat; width:120px; height:35px; float:left; ">
        <a style="color:lightgrey;" href="someLink" id="wellsButton" >
            <img style="float:left; padding:8px 0px 41px 7px;" id="DivBtn5" name="DivBtn5" src="buttons/wells_text.png" border="0">
            </div>
                <div id="wellsFilter">
                <p class="toolheader">Well Age Group</p>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="markers/Wells1.png" />
                            <label>Today</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" checked onclick='boolToday=!boolToday;filterWellLicenses();'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        ...
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
        </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#wellsFilter
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:980px;
    top:35px;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    border:1px solid #828282;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    _padding-top: 10px; /*for IE only*/
    _padding-bottom: 10px; /*for IE only*/
    /*width:230px;*/
    opacity:0.93;
    filter:alpha(opacity=93); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    z-index: 1000000000; /* Be on top of splitter */
}

#wellsFilter img
{
    float:left;
}



#wellsFilter label
{
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#wellsFilter input
{
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

#wellsFilter .toolheader
{
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#tabs:hover+#wellsFilter
{
    display:block;
}

#wellsButton:hover + #wellsFilter
{
    display:block;
}

#wellsFilter:hover
{
    display:block;
}
```

Why does my popup stop working as soon as the elements are within a parent div container?
I have tried a wide variety of padding and absolute value settings, but nothing has worked.

EDIT - Removing the javascript links as people thought they were the issue.

EDIT - Adding the wellsFilter code

EDIT - updated the HTML code to match what is on the page and updated the CSS with my new attempt to fix it.

Comment: can you share your js?

Comment: the JS doesnt have anything to do with it

Comment: Where is the `#wellsFilter` in your HTML?

Comment: @DrydenLong i will update question to have it. sorry i forgot to add it haha

Comment: Where is the `#wellsFilter` in relation to the `#wellsButton` HTML? Could you post it all together as it appears on your site?

Comment: sorry, i was confused by the missing `#wellsFilter` since I thought you might be generating it dynamically. The `adjacent` selector is only going to work if it's applied to the other div, since they have to be directly successive elements:
`#tabs:hover+#wellsFilter`

Comment: @jbr3zy i added <code>#tabs:hover+#wellsFilter
{
 display:block; 
}'' </code>    to the css file but still didnt work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9HEZ3/ what browser?

Comment: @jordan.peoples does the `#wellsFilter` come right after the `#tabs`?

Comment: @jordan.peoples: even if it doesn't come right after, you can use the `general sibling` selector, which will work as long as the element is successive: `#tabs:hover~#wellsFilter`  http://jsfiddle.net/xv6em/

Comment: @jbr3zy check out the updated code and CSS, i have tried to propagate the hover event through the three divs, but still isnt appearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be your `adjacent` selector. The `+` sign will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the former element. Meaning if `#wellsFilter` isn't immediately preceded by `#wellsButton` it won't work.

You will need to have something like this:

```
<div id="tabs" style="width:100%">
    <a  href="somelink" id="wellsButton" >
        <img style="float:left; padding:8px 0px 41px 7px;" src="buttons/wells_text.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div id="wellsFilter">
    <p class="toolheader">Age Group</p>
</div>
```

And then change this:

```
#wellsButton:hover + #wellsFilter
{
    display:block;
}
```

To this:

```
#tabs:hover + #wellsFilter
{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Like in the code? preceeded in the code, as in the line immediately above it?

Comment: @jordan.peoples Pretty much yeah. `#wellsButton:hover + #wellsFilter` will only work if the very next element after `#wellsButton` is `#wellsFilter`. We'll need to see your code as a whole in order to see exactly what's wrong though.

Comment: I have updated the code in the question to match what is on my page.  It still doesnt work.  Since i have three divs, tab, wellsbutton and wellsfilter, I have changed the CSS to attempt to propgate the hover event down, but to no avail.

Comment: i moved the wellsfitler inside of my wellstab div and then changed the adjacent selected to be #DivBtn5:hove + #wellsFilter